# Can auto-predicted values ever improve linear regression?

Tags: multiple-regression, predictive-models, prediction, prediction-interval

You want to predict values of $y$ using a linear model of the following form:

1. $ y = \beta_0 + \beta_1x_1 + \beta_2x_2 + \beta_3x_3$

$y$ is significantly dependent upon all three variables. Unfortunately, for theoretical or practical reasons (not reasons of bias or error), you can't include $x_1$ and must use model #2:

2. $ y = \beta_{0.2} + \beta_{2.2}x_2 + \beta_{3.2}x_3$

Now, you cleverly use $x_2$ and $x_3$ to predict $x_1$ and make model #4:

3. $ x_1 = \beta_{0.3} + \beta_{2.3}x_2 + \beta_{3.3}x_3$
4. $ y = \beta_{0.4} + \beta_{1.4}\hat{x_1} + \beta_{2.4}x_2 + \beta_{3.4}x_3$

**Have you gained any new information about individual values of $y$? Will (4) ever be a better predictor of single observations of $y$ (and intervals) than (2)?**

Comment: There are a lot of things to consider and also related to your other question. For some reason you can't use x1 but somehow you have equation 3. Are you assuming that it has been given to you? Also are you assuming that all fitting tasks are performed using OLS? Is the true model linear with gaussian noise, etc?

Comment: I see no difference in the *predictions* between models 2 and 4: both of them express $y$ as an affine combination of $x_2$ and $x_3$, with no restrictions on the parameters, so they *must* have identical fits. Model 4 is obviously unidentifiable, however, because it uses four parameters where three will do. Arguably, then, model 4 is always a *worse* procedure to use than model 2 in the sense that you work harder to estimate the coefficients and you do so in a way that obfuscates their meanings. What, then, do you mean by "better predictor"?

Comment: @whuber: Thanks for the deep questions about my loose language. I think I would say "better = returns smaller valid confidence intervals at a given test criterion (valid meaning if 95% of values with $X_0$ predicted to have $y_0 \pm CI$, an infinite population would confirm)." That may still not be precise?

Comment: Well, when two OLS models give the same predictions, they will have the same prediction intervals, too.  The models will differ, though, in terms of the confidence intervals they can supply for the parameter estimates: model 4 won't be able to do that because of the collinearity.